# Camera Translation in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glut, glm-math

I am trying to do a class to walk through the world in OpenGL, but I am having problems with the mathematics. My idea here is to use the function lookAt from glm to set the observer in the position I wanted, and then just operate with the points that I pass to the function. 
I think the functions to do rotations that I made are correct, but the translation part in the walk method seems to be wrong, and when I try to walk in the world if I just translate, or just rotated, things go right, but when I do both things just get messed.

here is the class so far:

```
#ifndef OBSERVER_H
#define OBSERVER_H

#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

class Observer {

private:

    glm::vec3 eye, center, upp;

public:

    glm::mat4 view;

    Observer() {}
    ~Observer() {}    

    void initialize(glm::vec3 eye, glm::vec3 center, glm::vec3 upp);
    void walk(GLfloat distance);
    void pitch(GLfloat pitch);
    void yaw(GLfloat yaw);
    void roll(GLfloat roll);
    void setView();
};

void Observer::initialize(glm::vec3 eye, glm::vec3 center, glm::vec3 upp) 
{
    this->eye = eye;
    this->center = center;
    this->upp = upp;
}

void Observer::walk(GLfloat distance) 
{
    glm::vec3 vector = glm::normalize(center - eye);
    glm::vec3 translate = vector*distance - vector;

    eye += translate;
    center += translate;
    upp += translate;
}

void Observer::roll(GLfloat roll) {
    glm::mat4 rotate(1.0f);

    rotate = glm::rotate(rotate, roll, glm::vec3(center - eye));

    center = glm::vec3(rotate * glm::vec4(center, 1.0f));
    upp = glm::vec3(rotate * glm::vec4(upp, 1.0f));
}

void Observer::yaw(GLfloat yaw) {
    glm::mat4 rotate(1.0f);

    rotate = glm::rotate(rotate, yaw, glm::vec3(upp - eye));

    center = glm::vec3(rotate * glm::vec4(center, 1.0f));
    upp = glm::vec3(rotate * glm::vec4(upp, 1.0f));
}

void Observer::pitch(GLfloat pitch) {
    glm::mat4 rotate(1.0f);
    glm::vec3 cross = glm::cross(center - eye, upp - eye);

    rotate = glm::rotate(rotate, pitch, cross);

    center = glm::vec3(rotate * glm::vec4(center, 1.0f));
    upp = glm::vec3(rotate * glm::vec4(upp, 1.0f));
}

void Observer::setView() 
{
    view = glm::lookAt(eye, center, upp);
}

#endif
```

So right before I starting draw things I set the view matrix with this class in other part in the program. Can someone tell me if my maths are right?

Answer (score 2):

When you `walk`, you only want to transform the eye and center position, not the `upp` vector. Just remove the `upp += translate;` line.